# Possible to route all LAN traffic through router configured with my VPN service?

Tags: routing, vpn

I have a paid VPN service (mullvad) and I wondered if it would be possible to route all my WAN traffic mullvad's VPN via an Asus RT-AC66U wireless router running DD-WRT v24 sp2. I guess what i'm asking is, is it possible to configure my router such that any node on my LAN is filtered through? I see that DD-WRT has some PPTP and OpenVPN configs but I'm not really sure what I'm doing. This has been reinforced by my recent "C" in Networking hence the reason for my query to the wise ol nerds on my favorite fourm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have such a router to test, but it looks like it's totally possible.

According to Mullvad, you can use an OpenVPN client (see their FAQ, https://www.mullvad.net/en/v2/faq), and according to DD-WRT you should certainly be able to set up the router as an OpenVPN client.

See their "easy way" tutorial:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN_%28the_easy_way%29_v24%2B

Or the other tutorial:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN

Notice that either tutorial seems to be mostly concerned with setting up the router as a server, but they both have sections for setting up the router as a client.

Comment: It sure does seem like it's possible... Thanks!